# Why esriSpatialRelTouches relation does not work?

Tags: arcobjects, vba, vb.net

I have two feature layers. The first one is just a polygon and the other one consists of a series of polygons which are enclosed by the first one. Thus, some polygons of the second feature layer touch on the boundaries of the first feauture layer. I wrotre a code (the basic part shown below to identify which polygons of the second layer touches the boundary of the polygon in the first layer but while the code runs without a problem it does not identify (e.g. by giving FID with Msgbox) any such polygon whilsty it should.
Any help please?

```
Dim pBlockBoundaryFC  As IFeatureClass
Set pBlockBoundaryFC = pBlockBoundary.FeatureClass


Dim pBlockBoundaryFields  As IFields
Set pBlockBoundaryFields = pBlockBoundaryFC.Fields

Dim pGeom As IGeometry


Dim pSpatialFilter As ISpatialFilter
Set pSpatialFilter = New SpatialFilter

Dim pBlockBoundaryCursor As IFeatureCursor
Set pBlockBoundaryCursor = pBlockBoundaryFC.Search(pSpatialFilter, False)


Set pBlockBoundaryFeature = pBlockBoundaryCursor.NextFeature
Do Until pBlockBoundaryFeature Is Nothing

Set pGeom = pBlockBoundaryFeature.Shape
With pSpatialFilter
```

'**************************
'Conversion
Dim pPolygonBoundary As ITopologicalOperator
Set pPolygonBoundary = pFeature.Shape

Set pGeom = pPolygonBoundary.Boundary
'*************************

```
Set .Geometry = pGeom
    .GeometryField = "Shape"
    .SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelTouches
End With

Dim pRelOp As IRelationalOperator
Set pRelOp = pGeom

  Set pNewParcelsFeature = pNewParcelsCursor.NextFeature
  Do Until pNewParcelsFeature Is Nothing

    FID = pNewParcelsFeature.Value(intposFID)
    If pRelOp.Touches(pNewParcelsFeature.Shape) Then

    ''Report the FID of each parcel that 'touches' the exetrnal boundary
    MsgBox FID
    End If

Set pNewParcelsFeature = pNewParcelsCursor.NextFeature

Loop


Set pBlockBoundaryFeature = pBlockBoundaryCursor.NextFeature

Loop
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few concepts that I see you are missing. I will try to explain them.

1- The first one has to do with spatial filter usage. **You should pass a filter when you are using it, otherwise, just pass nothing.**

You have this code:

```
Dim pSpatialFilter As ISpatialFilter
Set pSpatialFilter = New SpatialFilter

Dim pBlockBoundaryCursor As IFeatureCursor
Set pBlockBoundaryCursor = pBlockBoundaryFC.Search(pSpatialFilter, False)
```

Why do this? It seems you want to pass Nothing to loop through every single feature (and by the way, you should make that **False** a **True**) [You want to use a recycling cursor](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/componenthelp/esriGeodatabase/IFeatureClass_Search.htm).  But that is a different discussion.

2.- **You are modifying the spatial filter's geometry while you are looping**. **That is the reason your results are all out of whack**. Do not ever ever ever ever do that, unless the geometry ownership has been transfered using the [FilterOwnsGeometry property](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/FilterOwnsGeometry_Property/00250000083p000000/).

There are ways to make this much much faster, but a simpler (non-optimal) version of what you want is (in pseudo code):

```
cursor = boundaryFC.search(Nothing, True)
for every feature returned by cursor
   create spatial filter
   spatialfilter.geometry =  feature.shape
   spatialfilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelTouches

   secondCursor = parcelFC.search(spatialfilter)
   for every parcelFeature returned by secondCursor
     debug.print parcelFeature.objectid
   next parcelFeature

next feature
```

That should do the trick. There are ways to make this faster, but it will do for now.

Comment: What Does FilterOwnsGeometry even do?

Comment: havk for internal memory management. If the filter owns the geometry, then in each loop it can assume it won't change so you can save a deep clone of it in the internals. A classic case where this happens is when you use the geometry of a feature that came from a recycling cursor. On every iteration that geometry will change. Honestly, IMHO it should just always deep clone and forget about it.

Answer (score 2):

The borders have to match exactly in order to get results from IRelationalOperator::Touches.
From the [ArcGIS documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Touches_Method/002m00000346000000/%29):

> Two geometries are said to touch when the intersection of the
>   geometries is non-empty, but the intersection of their interiors is
>   empty.  Touches is a Clementini operator. For example, a point touches
>   a polyline only if the point is coincident with one of the polyline
>   end points.

I would convert the geometry from the first layer into a line (ITopologicalOperator::Boundary) and then use the crosses operator (IRelationalOperator::Crosses) to check if they intersect.

Comment: I tried it but it still does not work. However, I am not sure if I did Ok. Please, have a look in the code I added between the asterisks. Thanks

Comment: I think you should replace "If pRelOp.Touches(pNewParcelsFeature.Shape) Then" with "If pRelOp.Crosses(pNewParcelsFeature.Shape) Then"

Comment: Eventually, the 'touches' worked!